# Can I install programs on a live DVD, just to test them?

Tags: installation, package-management, livedvd

My Ubuntu's version is 12.04. Right now I'm using Windows, but as I've burned an Ubuntu image disk to a DVD, I want to know if it's possible to install programs on it, just to test them. Will it damage any part of the live DVD? I don't really want them to be there all the time. Is just for testing.

Comment: One of the LiveDVD advantages is that you can do whatever you want when you start your computer from it, including install applications. However, they are deleted when you restart or turn off the computer, so you can use it to test applications

Comment: Do you want to install the programs *running* Ubuntu or install on the Live edition so you have those programs installed when running every time? Please, make your question more clear, because right now it is "too open" and every new answer will be right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you **CAN** in fact install programs on it. It will work just like a normal system.

But this will all be true only till you reboot. Once you reboot, everything is gone, as the programs are stored in RAM.

So, again, you CAN install programs, its just that they won't remain there across reboots, unless you have set up a persistence file. Softwares like Unetbootin have a option to quickly do that.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Your live DVD is only storing datas in your RAM.

So, if you want to store informations/programs, you'll have to build your own persistant bootdisk.

You can look at the following website : http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/06/create-persistent-bootable-usb-drive.html